# Facebook requests not received

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

I have an app with Facebook requests integrated. When I send a request to an account, the notification appears on the Facebook.com website under notifications, but does not appear on the mobile facebook application running on IOS. If I open the notifications tab, I see all of the notifications that appear on the website, apart from mine. Is there a particular reason for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may have forgotten to put the settings for your iOS app into the settings for your app in your App Dashboard

If there's no iOS app configured, there would be no reason to show the requests in Facebook's mobile app because there's no way for the user to act on them

Comment: app on facebook and native ios apps are activated. any other?

Comment: Are the facebook login for iOS settings correct? app store ID, etc?

Comment: works now, thanks very much, it was the "mobile app" feature disabled

Comment: Hi Alessandro, where this "Mobile App" feature is located ?